# tmux ctrlp arrow keys not workin

Tags: vim, tmux

Running Ubuntu 15 and have tmux session open. Inside that session I open vim and hit Ctrl-p and start search for a file. When I hit the up arrow nothing happens.

If I do not open tmux and just open vim ctrl-p works just fine. Thoughts?

tmux.conf

```
setw -g xterm-keys on

# act like vim
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
bind-key -r C-h select-window -t :-
bind-key -r C-l select-window -t :+

# act like GNU screen
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a

# start window numbers at 1 to match keyboard order with tmux window order
set -g base-index 1
set-window-option -g pane-base-index 1

# renumber windows sequentially after closing any of them
set -g renumber-windows on

# soften status bar color from harsh green to light gray
set -g status-bg '#666666'
set -g status-fg '#aaaaaa'

# remove administrative debris (session name, hostname, time) in status bar
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right ''

# increase scrollback lines
set -g history-limit 10000

# switch to last pane
bind-key C-a last-pane

# Local config
if-shell "[ -f ~/.tmux.conf.local  ]" 'source ~/.tmux.conf.local'
```

Vimrc

```
set nocompatible

let mapleader = ","

set backspace=2
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set history=50
set ruler
set showcmd
set incsearch
set laststatus=2
set autoread

set ignorecase
set smartcase

set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround

set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·,nbsp:·

set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1

"set number

set splitbelow
set splitright

set winwidth=84
set winheight=5
set winminheight=5
set winheight=999

set matchpairs+=<:>

" Treat <li> and <p> tags like the block tags they are
let g:html_indent_tags = 'li\|p'

set scrolloff=8
set sidescrolloff=15
set sidescroll=1

" Load up all of our plugins
if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.bundles"))
    source ~/.vimrc.bundles
endif

filetype plugin indent on

" Dynamic line numbers
set rnu
function! ToggleNumbersOn()
    set nu!
    set rnu
endfunction
function! ToggleRelativeOn()
    set rnu!
    set nu
endfunction
autocmd FocusLost * call ToggleRelativeOn()
autocmd FocusGained * call ToggleRelativeOn()
autocmd InsertEnter * call ToggleRelativeOn()
autocmd InsertLeave * call ToggleRelativeOn()

map <Esc>[B <Down>]
```

Vimrc.bundles

```
if &compatible
    set nocompatible
end

filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-runner.git'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-run-interactive'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/ctags.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic' "Syntax Highlighting
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/tComment'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/HTML-AutoCloseTag'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive' "Make git awesome
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'

Plugin 'Slava/vim-spacebars'
Plugin 'groenewege/vim-less'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'

Plugin 'romainl/Apprentice'
Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline' "Awesome looking meta at bottom
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'

Plugin 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'
Plugin 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
Plugin 'mattn/calendar-vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype on

set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme gruvbox
syntax enable

" Plugin Tweaks
nnoremap <silent> <C-h> :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> :TmuxNavigateDown<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-k> :TmuxNavigateUp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :TmuxNavigateRight<cr>

"tmux integration
let g:tmux_navigator_no_mappings = 1
let g:tmux_navigator_save_on_switch = 1

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
nnoremap <C-t> :call ToggleRelativeOn()<cr>

" Ctrlp Settings
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|bower_components\|git'

" mapping for Vimwiki
autocmd FileType vimwiki map <leader>c :call ToggleCalendar() <cr>

let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'$HOME/Dropbox/vimwiki'}]

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1

map <Leader>ct :!ctags -R .<CR>

function! ToggleCalendar()
    execute ":Calendar"
    if exists("g:calendar_open")
        if g:calendar_open == 1
            execute "q"
            unlet g:calendar_open
        else
            g:calendar_open = 1
        end
    else
        let g:calendar_open = 1
    end
endfunction

" Setting up keyboard shortcuts for tabular
if exists(":Tabularize")
    nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
    vmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
    nmap <Leader>a: :Tabularize /:\zs<CR>
    vmap <Leader>a: :Tabularize /:\zs<CR>
endif

" Tagbar settings
nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

Here is what my terminal looks like when running tmux

[image]

Here how it looks without tmux

[image]

Comment: Is <C-p> mapped to something in your .tmux.conf? <C-b><C-?> in tmux should display all of your active key mappings

Comment: Does not look like it

Comment: My apologies, I misread your question. Try setting the xterm-keys option: `setw -g xterm-keys on`.

Comment: E492: Not an editor command: setw -g xterm-keys on

Comment: "E492: Not an editor command:" --> clearly a vim error, but the suggestion was a xterm setting

Comment: @jrock2004 : that's supposed to go in your tmux config

Comment: Did not work. I added some screenshots. Will show my .vimrc

Comment: Have you tried turning off your Vim plugins other than CtrlP and see if the behavior corrects itself? That would tell you if one of the other plugins is interfering.

Comment: @DanLowe how would you turn the plugins off after they are installed?

Comment: @jrock2004 that depends on which thing you are using to load plugins. I use Pathogen, which lets you define an ignore list in `.vimrc`. I would guess there are similar mechanisms available in Vundle and the other Vim plugin managers, though.

Comment: Actually looking at your post, I would guess you can simply comment them all out in the `Vimrc.bundles` file?

Comment: @DanLowe so did that and the problem is the colorscheme is breaking it. gruvbox. How can I figure out why?

Comment: So it seems that anything beyond vim builtin themes are breaking ctrlp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deactivating your Vim plugins (other than CtrlP) and see if the behavior corrects itself. That will tell you if one of the other plugins is interfering.

Your screenshots indicate that the colors differ when tmux is running. I notice that your `.vimrc` indicates 256-color mode:

```
set t_Co=256
```

Are you running tmux in 256-color mode?

```
tmux -2
```

I also wonder if you should not be declaring the tmux_navigator settings *before* you load the plugin via Vundle, e.g. move these two lines to before Vundle loads.

```
let g:tmux_navigator_no_mappings = 1
let g:tmux_navigator_save_on_switch = 1
```

Comment: what does tmux -2 do? starting tmux this way fixed it

Comment: It starts tmux in a mode that assumes a 256-color capable terminal.

Comment: sweet, well I just added an alias to always put that. Thanks